# Can't call Python 3 from cPanel cron jobs

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, cpanel, jail-shell

I add this in my cpanel cron jobs

```
python3.7 myscript.py
```

But I get this error

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: python3.7: command not found
```

But I can call `python3.7 myscript.py` from the command line just fine. How can I run it in cPanel cron jobs?

Comment: use `full/path/to/python3.7 full/path/to/myscript.py'. It can run it as different user, with differen privileges and different setings, and in different folder.

Comment: Yup, the full path solves it

Comment: I was using a different user indeed since I use the cpanel user

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I use the full path. It seems it is caused by me using a different user than root since I use cPanel. Weird it didn't happen when I use just `python` when I used Python 2.

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 myscript.py
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Command worked fine from the terminal but not as a cron job. Namecheap's docs say "For Python and Perl scripts, there is no need to use a full path to the environment" -- but it only worked when I included the full path, in my case when using a venv. Thanks.